# Sitecore performance: Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits set to "false"

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

So after following the suggestions on [this blog post](http://www.alen.me.uk/2012/11/content-tree-expands-slow-in-content.html) I noticed a significant (~300%) improvement in the loading times of Items in the Content Editor.

I am considering publishing this to our testing server for a few days and see how it behaves, are there any counter-indications about doing this on Production? Will cache stop growing when memory is full, or could it lead to server instability?

Additionally, would I notice a similar increase in performance if I was to enforce cache limit but set them to fill them the entire RAM of the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Sitecore Scaling Guide documentation:

> `<setting name="Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" value="true" />`
>
> Sitecore recommends that the cache size limits are disabled on 64-bit systems with ample memory

See http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/cms_tuning_guide_sc70-72-a4.pdf chapter 4.5.4.

I've tested this in few projects and there was only one issue - rebuilding Solr indexes took much longer then usually in **Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526** (20 minutes vs 6 hours). I haven't tested this with Lucene indexes.

It has been fixed in **Sitecore 7.2 rev. 141226 (7.2 Update-3)**. Except from that I haven't experienced any issues and it's recommended by the Sitecore to enable this settings so I think it is safe to do this (assuming you're running on 64-bit server).

If your site is based on earlier rev of **Sitecore 7.2** than **rev. 141226**, you may want to confirm this with Sitecore support that there are no more issues related to this setting.

Comment: Thanks, today being Friday I am not going to leave such an important change at its own devices over the weekend. I will tentatively change it on Monday and monitor the situation from there.

I will definitely come back and leave feedback.

Comment: Just checked your impressive profile. It is reassuring to receive feedback from such a professional!

Comment: We are running 141226, but we have Lucene indexes - will let you know. Thanks again for the hugely detailed answer!